# The size of the picture captured by Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I'm using my turtlebot' Kinect to capture some photo, does anyone know the size of the picture? Like
xxx * xxx pixel, or whether I can change the resolution. I know it's pretty dumb but it is because I cannot use my turtle right now.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228563/the-size-of-the-picture-captured-by-kinect/) by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think this will answer your question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/55689/lower-kinect-resolution-for-rgbcamera-using-openni_launch/

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-09**:
Oh! Thx! It's Exactly what I need!

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2016-03-10**:
Cool - can you please accept this answer :)